# How can I practice implementing data structures and algorithms?

Tags: learning, self-improvement, data-structures

I just finished learning the basics on data structures and algorithms using Python and C, completing some of the exercises from the book I read. I feel that it is necessary to implement some of these data structures and algorithms to enhance my understanding about the material that I just learned, such as the red-black tree and priority queue.

Are there any good websites with material for me to use when practicing?

Comment: There are tons of questions like this one already on [programmers.SE](programmers.stackexchange.org). Look for the `self-improvement` and `learning` tags.

Comment: @Simon, thanks for your advice. I will go and check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get an account on http://topcoder.com. They run competitions among programmers to tackle problems involving data structures and algorithms. You'll be competing on correctness, runtime, and speed of implementation. They also have some very good [tutorials](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index&module=Static).

Comment: Jay Elston mentioned the Cormen book on algorithms which is excellent. Another good book is _[Programming Interviews Exposed](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Interviews-Exposed-Secrets-Programmer/dp/047012167X)_ by Mongan, Suojanen, and Giguere. Google recommends this book for people coming in to interview (or at least they did, not too long ago).

Answer (score 3):

Start with a search.

Search for the words "Code Kata"

Read those web sites for examples of things you can write that will require data structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Pick up a copy of [Introduction to Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). Implement some of the algorithms.

Here is a list that will cover several interesting uses for data structures --

- linked lists
- binary search tree
- hash table
- Dijkstra's shortest path
- KMP string matching